# JInternalFrame Opening and Focus

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, pane

I've got a couple JInternalFrames inside a DesktopPane, and I've noticed something with the first time they open.

When I first open one, and then open a second one, the first JInternalFrame will be on top of the second.  I want them to open on top of each other, but this only happens the first time.  I realize now that it is because of the order that they are added.  But my program will be retrieving information right at the desktoppane load so I need the JIF variables to be added before the windows are actually opened.  So how can I make sure the window that is opened comes out on top regardless of the order they are added?

I would prefer not to use a dialogbox.

Comment: I can't recreate this issue on Windows, you might want to provide a short code example. You can use an `InternalFrameListener` and call `toFront` inside `internalFrameActivated`.

Comment: My code initializes multiple JIF's but keeps them invisible until the user opens the window.  So when they open I simply setVisible(true). I checked out InternalFrameListener, but it doesn't seem to have something for checking if setVisible(false); has been called.  Is there a way to do that? I don't have my JIF's disposed because the data needs to be kept until the program is closed.

Comment: Never mind, thank you! Simply calling toFront() when the window is set visible was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

I've create a sample application for you to understand...

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;

//This is a Internal Frame I have created
private PaymentInternalFrame payIF;


public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}


private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("Click");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jDesktopPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDesktopPane1);
    jDesktopPane1.setLayout(jDesktopPane1Layout);
    jDesktopPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jDesktopPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 412, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 529, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        



private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        if(payIF==null||payIF.isClosed()){
            payIF = new PaymentInternalFrame();
            mainDesktop.add(payIF);
            payIF.setVisible(true);
            payIF.setMaximum(true);
            payIF.isSelected();
        }else{
            payIF.setSelected(true);
        }
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        NotificationMessage.errorMessage(this, e);
    }
}                                        



//Main Method...


public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: above the constructor declare your code..                         
    YourInternalFrame yourInternalFrameObject;

Comment: Please explain your solution and put modifications or extensions into your post and not in comments.